# How can i display multiple preview images (that are loaded into an input)in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

So i'm developing a webpage for a photographer in ReactJS. I'm having troubles in one part specially. I want him to be able to select multiple pictures into an input (type=file), those same photos should be sent to the backend (but i can take care of that), and the pictures he chooses should be displayed in a Carousel, i was advised to do it with react-slick, i can manage myself with that. But i can't seem to find the way to extract the URL from each photo so i can pass it and map it into different html img tags.

This is the input

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="inputFotos"
    multiple
    onChange={handleChange}
    accept=".png, .jpg, .raw"
 />
```

This is the handleChange

```
const handleChange= e =>{
    setFotos([
        ...fotos,
        ...e.target.files
    ])
```

(I know this code doesn't even begin to solve the problem i'm asking for)
I tried something with FileReader but got nowhere, and also used URL.createObjectURL(fotos), but i read somewhere that it wasn't adviced to use it and it only worked for a single picture anyways.

How should i get those pictures URL's withouth having to send them backend? I want him to be able to see all of his selected pictures before submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview pictures without uploading to the server

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [preview_urls, set_preview_urls] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    set_preview_urls((prev) =>
      prev.concat(
        Array.from(e.target.files ?? []).map((f) =>
          window.URL.createObjectURL( f )
        )
      )
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      preview_urls.forEach((url) => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url));
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        id="inputFotos"
        multiple
        onChange={handleChange}
        accept=".png, .jpg, .raw"
      />
      <div>
        {preview_urls.map((url) => (
          <img key={url} src={url} alt="" />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm getting errors at
useState<string[]>
and
React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) saying something about typescript

Comment: Replace with `any`

Comment: If you are not using typescript, you can remove the type declaration

Answer (score 0):

first, you can save via convert file images to preview image URL.
The following function will set a base64 representation of the image in react state. so even after the input change event, it will remain unchanged.

```js
const savePreviewImageUrl = (setPreviewImages, file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setPreviewImages(previewImages => [...previewImages, reader.result])
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

`setPreviewImages` is a setter for the state which going to save preview images that can be used in the carousel.

```js
const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = useState([])
```

the `file` is each of file instance which are placed in `e.target.files`
Then, `handleChange` for input must also save preview images too.

```js
const handleChange = e => {
    setFotos([
        ...fotos,
        ...e.target.files
    ])

    Array.from(e.target.files || []).forEach(file => {
       savePreviewImageUrl(setPreviewImages, file)
    })
}
```

#### Note:

There might better option using `Promise` to define your savePreviewImageUrl function, and split the saving logic from URL grabber

Comment: I'm getting an error at [...e.target.files].forEach(file) precisely at the 3 dots in e.target.files

Comment: I update that section, it might not contain the files list correctly by function call time.

Let me know if that fix the problem, @Fran910